# Call func pearsonr and Got TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add

Tags: python, typeerror, pearson-correlation

I run the code below and get unexpected error 
 "TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add"
which X and Y are both dataframe

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
for i in range(X.shape[1]):
    Pear_corr, _ = pearsonr(Y,pd.DataFrame(X.iloc[:,i]))
```

what should I do ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the error was thrown because I had 2d numpy arrays of shape (1000,1) for Y and X. I flattened them (y_val.flatten(), y_predict.flatten()) and the error was fixed.

Comment: I also had the same issue when trying to apply it to 2d array, instead of 1d array